# File.write doesn't write

Tags: ruby, file

I'm enjoying a very interesting problem where `File.write...` only works occasionally, i.e., seemingly when it's at the *end* of the method. For some weird reason this works:

```
 def update(id)
   r = HTTParty.get("#{user_api_url}/#{id}?token=#{token}").parsed_response
   file_path = "/Users/#{server_user}/server/resources/users/"
   File.write("#{file_path}#{id}#{extension(r['user_file_name'])}", open("#{r['user_url']}").read, { mode: 'wb' })
   File.write("#{file_path}#{id}_logo#{extension(r['logo_file_name'])}", open("#{r['user_logo_url']}").read, { mode: 'wb' })
 end
```

And this doesn't:

```
 def update(id)
   r = HTTParty.get("#{user_api_url}/#{id}?token=#{token}").parsed_response
   file_path = "/Users/#{server_user}/server/resources/users/"
   r['shared_resources'].map do |key, value|
     file = "#{file_path}shared_resources/#{value.split('/')[-1]}"
     p "#{timestamp}: Saving #{key} from #{api_server}#{value} into #{file}"
     File.write(file, open("#{api_server}#{value}").read, mode: 'wb')
   end
   File.write("#{file_path}#{id}#{extension(r['user_file_name'])}", open("#{r['user_url']}").read, mode: 'wb')
   File.write("#{file_path}#{id}_logo#{extension(r['logo_file_name'])}", open("#{r['user_logo_url']}").read, mode: 'wb')
 end
```

The second method doesn't generate any errors at all, but no files are written. The paths and the URL are both correct. Makes me think I'm not opening or closing something correctly but I don't know what. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Getting this error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/user123/server/resources/users/shared_resources/cqap_logo_cmyk-6a82ebd2e336c92188a58cacf26792cf9f43b6d296ae51c2b3fe...
```

Which is from File.write in the loop.

**UPDATE 2**

The `r['shared_resources']` outputs this:

```
 {\"logo\"=>\"/assets/server/user123-6a82ebd2e336c92188a58cacf26792cf9f43b6d296ae51c2b3fe05a0c1802794.jpg\"}"
```

But nothing in the loop seems to do anything.

Comment: In second snippet `file_path` definition is gone.

Comment: Ah yeah, I know, it was moved into its own def.

Comment: Please show the actual code (both using same `file_path` etc,) and dry/cleanup the code so that it contained only meaningful failing calls and we could run it ourselves. That said, get rid of `api` etc.

Comment: and this is rails related to what ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `shared_resources` folder does not exist. First snippet writes directly in existing `file_path`, while second one tries to write into subfolder. Put the following right after you have `file_path` defined:

```
Dir.mkdir File.join file_path, 'shared_resources' # unless exists?
```

Comment: I thought so too, so making the directory manually or with that code doesn't help write the file.